# Dropdown control in semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I need some help using the dropdown control in semantic.
Te multiple selection is not working as expected. 
Here is the code:

```
                  <div class="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
                <input name="tag" type="hidden">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="default text">Tags</div>
                <div class="menu">
                  <div class="item" data-value="angular">Angular</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="css">CSS</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="design">Graphic Design</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="ember">Ember</div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and the script code

```
$('.tag .ui.dropdown').dropdown({allowAdditions: true});
```

A single select is the one thats works.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Err ... is there an element which contains the HTML snippet you have posted and has the class `tag`, such that the correct element will match `.tag .ui.dropdown` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using semantic-ui 2. Which version are you using?

See new UI elements here:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES.md#version-200---june-30-2015

Here you have your exact code running on plunker with version 2.0.8:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TPaqyX8f46H2K4eu59yp?p=preview

```
//Same code as in the question
       <div class="ui fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
            <input name="tags" type="hidden">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="default text">Tags</div>
            <div class="menu">
              <div class="item" data-value="angular">Angular</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="css">CSS</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="design">Graphic Design</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="ember">Ember</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @alfonso-presa ! I see my bad when checking you plunker example. 
I was running an old version of .js semantic.

Comment: Can we add any other attribute to the options here? I mean like adding tooltip for each option?